# How to pass a char parameter to a C DLL from a VB6 application?

Tags: c, vb6

I am trying to call a C function in my VB6 application. The problem is that that function takes simple `char` as a parameter. Not `char` array pointer (`char *`) but regular `char`.

This is how it is declared:

```
#define FM_API extern "C" int _stdcall
FM_API NVF_SetGroupFormat(char *aMarker, char aDecSeparator, int aDigits)
```

It returns -1 if execution was successful and 0 if not.

At the very beginning I did what I always do - just declared it and that is it.

This was my declaration:

```
Declare Function SetGroupFormat Lib "C:\Libs\FM_API.dll" Alias "NVF_SetGroupFormat" (ByVal lMarker As String, ByVal lDecSeparator As String, ByVal lDigits As Integer) As Integer
```

But it always returned 0 (fail/false).

I thought that is something wrong with parameters I passed. I called dll author for advice and told him how I pass my parameters. This is a call of that function:

```
Dim lSt As Integer
lSt = SetGroupFormat("=;\n", ".", 0)
```

Author told me that this call is correct but he told me that my declaration is "probably" wrong, because I declared lDecSeparator As String, but it should be char.

Main problem is that char does not exist in VB6.

How do I declare and pass char to a c based Dll from a VB6 code?

Comment: Double quotes is a string.  Single quotes is a char.

Comment: Try using Byte where you need a char.

Comment: @stark In VB6 if I try to write something like this lSt = SetGroupFormat("=;\n", '.', 0) it will be a syntax error. Char is not even declarable in VB6. VB.Net has Char but not VB6. If I remember correctly VBA does not have char type in general.

Comment: @EdneyHolder tried that too. decalerd like this 
`ByVal lDecSeparator As Byte`
and called like this:
`lSt = SetGroupFormat("=;\n", 46, 0)`
Same results

Comment: It should be ByRef since you don't pass the String by value.

Comment: @Lundin aDecSeparator is not a pointer so I guesed is should not be seen as reference type or something like that, but I tried changing  it to ByRef, same results. Unless you talk about aMarker.

Comment: Note, I removed the C++ tag from the question. Despite the fact that the DLL apparently happens to be written in C++, this is irrelevant for the question since VB6 native DLL imports happen exclusively via a C ABI interface.

Comment: A `Char` is the same binary representation as a VB6 `Byte`. So `Asc("A")`. `as byte` or `as any`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In VB6 you can use fixed-length strings for this purpose:

```vb
Declare Function SetGroupFormat Lib "C:\Libs\FM_API.dll" Alias "NVF_SetGroupFormat" ( _
    ByVal lMarker As String, _
    ByVal lDecSeparator As String * 1, _
    ByVal lDigits As Integer _
) As Integer
```

Admittedly it’s been a while since I used VB6, and my knowledge is a bit rusty; if the above syntax isn’t supported, then the following will definitely work:

```vb
Type SingleChar
    Value As String * 1
End Type

Declare Function SetGroupFormat Lib "C:\Libs\FM_API.dll" Alias "NVF_SetGroupFormat" ( _
    ByVal lMarker As String, _
    ByVal lDecSeparator As SingleChar, _
    ByVal lDigits As Integer _
) As Integer
```

Alternatively you can also use the data type `Byte` to represent a single 8-bit value, equivalent to `char` in the external API. If the call then fails, this is due to something else, unrelated to the parameter type.

Comment: I tried using Byte and passed 46 (ascii dot). Is this a correct way to pass byte as a char? Talking about user defined types, VB compiler does not allow passing them like that.

Comment: @MantasDaškevičius Yes, either `46` or equivalently `&H2E` should represent a dot character.

Comment: Well I will assume that there is something about this library and everything with declarations are fine. Function executes so there is not much I can do I guess. Thanks for the help. :)